# mysqli query always returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm running a query to a MySQL instance from php, it worked in a different file before and when I copied it over it always seem to return empty.

```
function getDelivery($eid, $raid){
    ChromePhp::log("eid:".$eid." raid:".$raid);
    $mysqli = getMysqliConnection();
    $q = "SELECT COMMENTS, DELIVERY_TIME FROM DELIVERY WHERE RAID = ? AND EID  = ?;";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss'. $raid, $eid);
    $stmt->bind_result($comments, $time);
    $stmt->execute();
if($stmt->fetch()){
    ChromePhp::log("TIME: ". $time);
    $data = array("comments" => $comments, "time" => $time ,"raid" =>$raid, "eid"=>$eid);
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    echo "{}";
}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
}
```

I used the chrome console to make sure eid and raid is not NULL, when I copied the query over to phpAdmin returned 1 result. but the fetch() seem to always return false, is there anything wrong with it that it always return nothing?

Comment: 1. Turn on error reporting for mysqli and PHP as shown in the linked question 2. **Browse to this file directly**, not via ajax call OR watch the error log for the errors. 3. Change dot for comma in bind_param call

Comment: Can we see the query output that works.

Comment: And the error that doesn't

Comment: @YourCommonSense I missed the dot in bind_params, stupid mistake, Thank you. That seems to be the only error

Comment: The only error is tha you are not watching PHP error messages. Otherwise you would have been notified of this issue already